# Modal popup does not appear

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do a popup for searching for staff from the database.

the popup only display if i didn't put "while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))". I've tried the same code on a different page without a popup. its working. when I tried to use the code for the popup, it's not working.

```
<!--Button to open the modal -->
<button class="myBtnSea" id="myBtnSea" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalSea"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModalSea" class="modalSea">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modalSea-content">
        <span class="closeSea">&times;</span>

        <div id="SearchStaff">
            <h3>Search for Staff</h3>
            <form action="search.php" method="POST">
                <div class="container">
                    <p>You can search either by name or IC number.</p>
                    <hr>

                    <input type="text" name="nama" placeholder="Search By Name" style="text-transform:uppercase"> <br><br>
                    <input type="text" name="icnum" placeholder="Search By IC Number" >

                    <button class="btn" name="search">Search</button><br><br>
                    <!--Table for display the data after search -->
                    <table id="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Department</th>
                            <th>Campus</th>
                        </tr>
                        <!--This code makes the popup does not appear -->            
                        <?php while ($row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['dept']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['campus']?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please share the button from where you are opening the modal

Comment: i've edited the code. :)

Comment: Can you please check the answer

Comment: it's still not working.

Comment: do you have any error ?

Comment: Please check updated code

Comment: there's no error. i've tried the updated code. but it's also not working .

Comment: have you added data-target in your button?

Comment: yes. i've added data target in my button. still same.

Comment: can you please update your code so I can check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You cannot change the classes of bootstrap in order to use it. You can only extend the classes otherwise the Bootstrap will not work. I have updated the whole code. Please try it.

```
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--Button to open the modal -->
    <button class="myBtnSea" id="myBtnSea" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalSea"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Modal</button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModalSea" class="modal fade modalSea" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content modalSea-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <span class="close closeSea" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
                </div>
                <div id="SearchStaff">
                    <h3>Search for Staff</h3>
                    <form action="search.php" method="POST">
                        <div class="container">
                            <p>You can search either by name or IC number.</p>
                            <hr>
                            <input type="text" name="nama" placeholder="Search By Name" style="text-transform:uppercase"> <br><br>
                            <input type="text" name="icnum" placeholder="Search By IC Number" >
                            <button class="btn" name="search">Search</button><br><br>
                            <!--Table for display the data after search -->
                            <table id="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Department</th>
                                    <th>Campus</th>
                                </tr>
                                <!--This code makes the popup does not appear -->          
                                <?php while ($row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['dept']?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['campus']?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Second, You have missed the `-` hyphen near `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. Please add it.

One more thing, before looping the result you should check the num rows returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error when looping here `$sql>fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` which should be something like this `$sql->fetchAll`
The proper syntax for using PDO to fetch all records is

`while ($row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`

you can view more about [PDOStatement::fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

**UPDATE:**

It seems you are not setting data-target and data-toggle in your button

`<button class="myBtnSea" id="myBtnSea" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalSea"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>`

Comment: this line is not updated yet <?php while ($row = $sql>fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>

Comment: I am not seeing data-toggle="modal" in your button as well